# How to cropping circle image openvc android

Tags: android, image, opencv

I want to crop a circle shape in an image.
I have an input image that is gray scale.
In this image have a circle shape. I need it.
 How to do it using Open CV on Android?

Input image:

[image: enter link description here]

```
Bitmap bmpProces = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+inpuImage);
Mat imageMat = new Mat ( bmpProces.getHeight(), bmpProces.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8U);
Bitmap myBitmap32 = bmpProces.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, imageMat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a mask,fill a circle in it according coordinates of target and use `CopyTo` to extract target circular area in your mask.Then you can crop a normal bounding rectangle of circle in mask Mat.You can see sample code and some more details [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/18784/crop-image-using-hough-circle/?answer=18796#post-id-18796).There is a snippet code that you can convert it to java and use it:

```
// center and radius are the results of HoughCircle
// mask is a CV_8UC1 image with 0
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros( img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1 );
circle( mask, center, radius, Scalar(255,255,255), -1, 8, 0 ); //-1 means filled
img.copyTo( dst, mask ); // copy values of img to dst if mask is > 0.
```